# how to run parallel job in python

Tags: python

I am doing a data mining project in Python, and during the experiment phase I have to run many experiments at the same time. How could I create `n` processes, so that each process is dedicated to an experiment? Which module I should use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [Does python support multiprocessor/multicore programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203912/does-python-support-multiprocessor-multicore-programming)

Then look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing for more options

but generally python multiprocessing(http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module will be enough

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.