# parallel file parsing, multiple CPU cores

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I asked a related but very general question earlier (see especially [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939912/python-execution-speed-laptop-vs-desktop/3939948#3939948)).

This question is very specific. This is all the code I care about:

```
result = {}
for line in open('input.txt'):
  key, value = parse(line)
  result[key] = value
```

The function `parse` is completely self-contained (i.e., doesn't use any shared resources).

I have Intel i7-920 CPU (4 cores, 8 threads; I think the threads are more relevant, but I'm not sure).

What can I do to make my program use all the parallel capabilities of this CPU?

I assume I can open this file for reading in 8 different threads without much performance penalty since disk access time is small relative to the total time.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I run ActiveState Python 3.1.2 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

cPython does not provide the threading model you are looking for easily.  You can get something similar using the `multiprocessing` module and a [process pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

such a solution could look something like this:

```
def worker(lines):
    """Make a dict out of the parsed, supplied lines"""
    result = {}
    for line in lines.split('\n'):
        k, v = parse(line)
        result[k] = v
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # configurable options.  different values may work better.
    numthreads = 8
    numlines = 100

    lines = open('input.txt').readlines()

    # create the process pool
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=numthreads)

    # map the list of lines into a list of result dicts
    result_list = pool.map(worker, 
        (lines[line:line+numlines] for line in xrange(0,len(lines),numlines) ) )

    # reduce the result dicts into a single dict
    result = {}
    map(result.update, result_list)
```

Comment: and using processes is better anyway for this use case

Comment: code using `multiprocessing` performs significantly better on operating systems with `fork` (linux) than without (windows) if the amount of shared state (the dict returned by `worker()`) because on those platforms, shared data must be pickled and sent over a pipe in the child process and unpickled in the parent process.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination you mean on windows it needs to be pickled, not on linux right? And you meant if the amount of shared state is large, rt?

Comment: Is this code really working for anyone? My apologies, new to python; still figuring my way out. The split won't work for list object here.

Comment: @knowone if you need help please post a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination It'd have been duplicate to some extent as your answer was almost what I need. It wasn't meant to belittle the approach or something. I was trying the code and got stuck, so asked here only.

Comment: @knowone i can't help you solve the problem you're having with your code without seeing your code.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination Is there any better approach for a large text files? I'm having problem because of `readlines()` as it loads all the lines in the memory. My file size is 23 GB and my memory is just 8 gigs.

Answer (score 8):

1. split the file in 8 smaller files
2. launch a separate script to process each file
3. join the results

Why that's the best way...

- That's simple and easy - you don't have to program in any way different from linear processing.
- You have the best performance by launching a small number of long-running processes.
- The OS will deal with context switching and IO multiplexing so you don't have to worry about this stuff (the OS does a good job).
- You can scale to multiple machines, without changing the code at all
- ...

Comment: Most effective way to do step 2: bash.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), which is a library for writing parallel and distributed Python.

To run the code below, first create `input.txt` as follows.

```
printf "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n" > input.txt
```

Then you can process the file in parallel by adding the `@ray.remote` decorator to the `parse` function and executing many copies in parallel as follows

```
import ray
import time

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def parse(line):
    time.sleep(1)
    return 'key' + str(line), 'value'

# Submit all of the "parse" tasks in parallel and wait for the results.
keys_and_values = ray.get([parse.remote(line) for line in open('input.txt')])
# Create a dictionary out of the results.
result = dict(keys_and_values)
```

Note that the optimal way to do this will depend on how long it takes to run the `parse` function. If it takes one second (as above), then parsing one line per Ray task makes sense. If it takes 1 millisecond, then it probably makes sense to parse a bunch of lines (e.g., 100) per Ray task.

Your script is simple enough that the multiprocessing module can also be used, however as soon as you want to do anything more complicated or want to leverage multiple machines instead of just one machine, then it will be much easier with Ray.

See the [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `multiprocessing` module, but if parse() is quick, you won't get much performance improvement by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As TokenMacGuy said, You can use `multiprocessing` module. If You really need to parse massive amount of data, You should check out the **[disco project](http://discoproject.org/)**.

> **Disco** is a distributed computing
>   framework based on the MapReduce
>   paradigm. Disco is open-source;
>   developed by Nokia Research Center to
>   solve real problems in handling
>   massive amounts of data.

It really scales up for jobs where Your parse() job is "pure" (i.e., doesn't use any shared resources) and is CPU intensive. I tested a job on a single core and then compared to running it on 3 hosts with 8 cores each. It actually ran **24 times faster** when run on the Disco cluster (NOTE: tested for an unreasonably CPU intensive job).

Answer (score 0):

- make distributed architecture with rabbitMQ, one task producer read file line  by line and send lines to workers via rabbitMQ
- use console utility like unix/parallel, xargs

  ```
  $ python makelist.py | parallel -j+2 'wget "{}" -O - | python parse.py'
  ```

  or this style

```
$ ls *.wav | xargs -n1 --max-procs=4 -I {} lame {} -o {}.mp3
```

Anyway, you need to realize map/reduce paradigm