# How to use parallel processing to call the same function multiple times?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

How to make this task much faster to be finished? The 3 calls of generate_ngrams_from_file() can be done in parallel? Just get into python and don't know how to make it faster. I think multiprocessing or threading should be doing the job, but no idea of how to do it.  This looks like a typical task can be done concurrently to use multiple cores on my Mac machine.

```
def tokenize(text):
   return [token for token in text.split(' ')]

def generate_ngrams(text, n):

    tokens = tokenize(text)

    ngrams = zip(*[tokens[i:] for i in range(n)])

    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

def generate_ngrams_from_file(input, out, n):
    count = 0
    with open(input, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            count += 1
            if line:
                ngrams = generate_ngrams(line, n)
                if n == 2:
                    bigrams.update(ngrams)
                elif n == 3:
                    trigrams.update(ngrams)
                elif n == 4:
                    fourgrams.update(ngrams)
                elif n == 5:
                    fourgrams.update(ngrams)

    print("Ngram done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()

    input_file = 'bigfile.txt'
    output_3_tram = '3gram.txt'
    output_4_tram = '4ngram.txt'
    output_5_tram = '5ngram.txt'

    print('Generate trigram: ')
    generate_ngrams_from_file(input_file, output_3_tram, 3)

    print("Generate fourgrams: ")
    generate_ngrams_from_file(input_file, output_4_tram, 4)

    print("Generate fivegrams: ")
    generate_ngrams_from_file(input_file, output_5_tram, 5)

    end = time.time()
    mytime(start, end)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parallel file parsing, multiple CPU cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047789/parallel-file-parsing-multiple-cpu-cores)

Comment: [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example)

Comment: This is a classic case for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) or even [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading in Python is not a very good idea because of the Global Interpreter Lock feature of Python. You can read about it here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-python-global-interpreter-lock-gil/. Multiprocessing is a better option to make your programs faster. You can put the `generate_ngrams()` function inside the `Process` class of `multiprocessing` module. Read about the `Process` class at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. `Process` class is recommended as it is faster than both `pool.apply()` and `pool.apply_async()`