# Passing target function arguments to Thread constructor

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a file with several thousand records and a list of regular expressions. I’d like to take each record in the file in turn and evaluate it against my list of regular expressions to a point where a match if found.

I created a single threaded script and it does the job but is very slow. To make it multithreaded I made the following adjustments:

1. Created the `run_target()` function that is be passed to the Thread constructor
2. Created 5 worker threads
3. Added the target function to the `check_file()` function.

Question: `run_target()` takes 2 arguments that I pass to it with each iteration of the `while` loop in the `check_file()` function. Do I need to somehow pass the arguments to the constructor when I create worker threads or shall I leave it as default? Or, should I pass keyword arguments with default values?

Also, is there a better or smarter way to tackle this. Thanks in advance.

```
def run_target(key, expr):
    matchStr = re.search(expr, key, re.I)
    if matchStr:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


for i in range(number_of_threads):
    worker = Thread(target = run_target(), args = ())
    worker.daemon = True
    t.start()


def check_file():

    for key, value in data.items():
        while True:
            expr = q.get()
            result = run_target(key, expr)
            if result == 1:
                lock.acquire()
                print ‘Match found’
                lock.release()
                break
            q.task_done()
        q.join()
```

Comment: I don't understand this code at all. Your loop will create threads that try to run `run_target`, but they'll all fail since you're passing an empty tuple of arguments. Then `check_file` calls `run_target` itself, completely separate from the threads. Are you wanting to make a thread-pool or something (e.g. `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`)? In any case, I don't expect you'll get any speedup using threads for regular expression matching, since the work is CPU bound and the GIL will prevent any real concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your first question - yes, as per [the threading library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) the function arguments need to be passed in `Thread` constructor. So instead of `worker = Thread(target = run_target(), args = ())` you need something like `worker = Thread(target = run_target, args = (key, expr))`. Note no braces after `run_target`.

The code you have posted does not seem to do what you are intending, anyway. IMO, to achieve your goals, the better strategy is to have a function that takes a regex as an argument, and do the entire processing of the file in that function. And then spawn several threads with `Thread(target = process_file, args = (expr,))` (note the comma after `expr`).

Note, that there is a known hurdle with threads in the most popular python distro, that make them useless on multicore CPUs - see more in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542982/2291425). If that is the case on your system, then using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is a good alternative - the high level API is quite similar.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you Evgeney. Excellent answer. This is what I was looking for.