# Using both vCPU's with google cloud computing. Python code. PyTorch

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch

I am new to cloud computing. I made a virtual machine in google cloud computing, machine type:

`e2-highcpu-2 (2 vCPU's, 2 GB geheugen)`

I run a script with running the command

`python3 simulation1.py`

When I look at the output control screen, I note that only 50% of the CPU power is used. So I just use one of my 2 CPU's. Is there a way to make full use of the computing power ?

Comment: Without more details, we are not able to know if your code takes advantage of both cores. Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question can be resumed to "is Python capable of running on multiple cores?"

And you can find the answer to that question perfectly explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542957/is-python-capable-of-running-on-multiple-cores).

Basically:

Python threads cannot take advantage of many cores. This is due to an internal implementation detail called the GIL (global interpreter lock) in the C implementation of python.

You can either use something like [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) or [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/) to split the parallel work into another process;

Or you can use something like [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) or [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) to use an alternative interpreter that doesn't have a GIL.

If you are already using any of the tools mentioned above. you could also add more details about your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not make use of above libraries. I'll to implement them

Comment: @Rens if the answer was useful mark it as good please.