# Most elegant/efficient/Pythonic way to calculate multiple parallel arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

For some econometric work.

I often need to derive multiple parallel arrays of calculated variables given a (potentially) large number of parallel data arrays.

In the following example, I have two input arrays and two output arrays, but imagine in the real world there could by anywhere from 5-10 input and output arrays.

w, x are inputs
y, z are outputs

Method A:

```
w = [1, -2, 5]
x = [0, 3, 2]
N = len(w)
I = range(N)
y = map(lambda i: w[i] + x[i], I)
z = map(lambda i: w[i] - x[i], I)
```

Method B:

```
w = [1, -2, 5]
x = [0, 3, 2]
N = len(w)
I = range(N)
y, z = [], []
for i in I:
  y.append(w[i] + x[i])
  z.append(w[i] - x[i])
```

Method C:

```
w = [1, -2, 5]
x = [0, 3, 2]
y, z = [], []
for w_i, x_i in zip(w, x):
  y.append(w_i + x_i)
  z.append(w_i - x_i)
```

Method D:

```
w = [1, -2, 5]
x = [0, 3, 2]
N = len(w)
I = range(N)
(y, z) = transpose(map(lambda i: [w[i] + x[i], w[i] - x[i]], I))
```

D seems to be the most concise, extendable, and efficient. But it's also the most difficult to read, especially with many variables with complicated formulae.

A is my favorite, with a little duplication, but is it less efficient to construct a loop per vairable? Will this not scale with large data?

B vs. C: I know C is more pythonic but B seems more convenient and concise, and scales better with more variables. In both cases, I hate the extra line where I have to declare the variables up-front.

Overall, I am not perfectly satisfied with any of the above approaches. Is there something missing from my reasoning or is there a better method out there?

Comment: Have you considered using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)? Most scientific computing in Python is done in numpy. In numpy, this would just be `y = w + x; z = w - x`.

Comment: @senshin, why not `y, z  = w + x,  w - x`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I mean, does it matter? They both do the same thing.

Comment: @senshin, yes one is pythonic the other is not.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Come on, you know I used a semicolon because you can't have newlines in comments.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Dude, what is your point? Assignment via tuple unpacking and assignment via separate statements do literally the same thing in this case.

Comment: @senshin, Dude I already made my point,  the OP is looking for a pythonic way to do something so I simply wanted to point out the pythonic way to do multiple assignments. Not really a big issue I was making a simple point.

Comment: @senshin Thanks for the tip. I had not consider that syntax because I did not know you could do that. It turned out my variables were already arrays, too.

Comment: @cas5nq Oh, so you're already using numpy? In that case, you should definitely read a numpy tutorial (e.g. http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial), because there's a lot of neat mathematical manipulations you can do in numpy that aren't possible in vanilla python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use numpy ... that performs the operations in C++ so its much faster ... (especially if we assume your arrays are much bigger than 3 items)

```
w = numpy.array([1, -2, 5])
x = numpy.array([0, 3, 2])

y = w+x
z = w-x
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a winner. So simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

i think @Beasley's suggestion works well, and i suggest using `multiprocessing` on top of it so that the output generation is in parallel. your computation seems perfectly parallelizable!

what i can offer can't beat the tips discussed on here:
[Does python support multiprocessor/multicore programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203912/does-python-support-multiprocessor-multicore-programming)