# Does the zlib module release the global interpreter lock (GIL) in Python 3?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, gil

There is a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203912/does-python-support-multiprocessor-multicore-programming/204150#comment30403986_204210) on an other question that says it does, but it would be good to have this information clearly stated as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per a note in the "Releasing the GIL from extension code" section of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code), the GIL is released by the zlib module when compressing data.